# Getting OpenAMToken with SAML

Tags: node.js, express, saml-2.0, openam

My express project uses passport-saml and OpenAM 13.0.0 to authenticate the user and then redirect to the main page of the application.

My express application is the remote service provider and I use OpenAM as the Identity Provider.

I get a SAML response within my express project, but I want to get the value of the OpenAMToken within my express project.

I know, the value is saved within the session cookie(named iPlanetDirectoryPro by default) and that it is possible to receive the OpenAMToken in response to an HTTP POST request (named tokenId).

But I have not found a way to get the value within express.

I also know, that OpenAM provides the STS, which translates OpenAM token to SAML token/assertion response, but not vice versa.

Is there a way to get the value of the OpenAM token/iPlanetDirectoryPro cookie in express/node.js?

Comment: Why would you need the OpenAM SSOToken at all? This is the OpenAM proprietary way, whereas SAML is the standards based way.

Comment: I am just wondering, if there is an easy way to get the OpenAM token of the current session, which was started through SAML, within express/node.js. Instead of having to look into the cookies of the browser.

Comment: There is no such way.
It would even be questionable if you write your own TokenType handler for the STS as it would be impossible to find out the SSO session from a SAML assertion, which would be passed to the STS.
A hack would be to send the SSOTokenID as a SAML attribute in the SAML Response, but this requires a custom SAML IdP attribute mapper as the default IdP AttributeMapper does not offer this.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the information. How can one make a custom SAML IdP attribute mapper? I have taken a look around, but not found a good explanation about it.

Comment: You just need to implement the interface https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/apidocs/com/sun/identity/saml2/plugins/IDPAttributeMapper.html

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Implement it where? In my express project? Or in the OpenAM settings?

Comment: You need to incorporate your implementation into the OpenAM web app (either as library or class) and configured it at the hosted IdP , property 'Attribute Mapper' (https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/admin-guide/#idp-assertion-processing)

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Bernhard Thalmayr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1740662/bernhard-thalmayr), I found an answer.

Sadly there is no easy way to get the OpenAM token, but it seems to be possible with a custom attribute mapper.